# Vue - prevent item dragging in a grid

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I created a grid of items using [this library](https://jbaysolutions.github.io/vue-grid-layout/guide/01-basic.html) and it works flawlessly. In my items, i have a very simple bootstrap grid with some forms, inputs and other content, the problem is that a lot of times while using the content inside of the bootstrap grid, i move the entire item.

I was wondering if there is a way to disable dragging **only** inside of the  so that when i use what's inside of the container, the item is not moved, but if i want to move the item i can drag it by grabbing it outside the container.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
    <grid-layout :layout.sync="layout"
                 :col-num="1"
                 :row-height="30"
                 :is-draggable="draggable"
                 :is-resizable="resizable"
                 :vertical-compact="true"
                 :use-css-transforms="true"
    >
        <grid-item v-for="item in layout"
                   :static="item.static"
                   :x="item.x"
                   :y="item.y"
                   :w="item.w"
                   :h="item.h"
                   :i="item.i"
        >
        
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-7">Here is some content...</div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">Here is some other content.. </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        </grid-item>
    </grid-layout>
</template>

<script>
import { GridLayout, GridItem } from "vue-grid-layout"
export default {
    components: {
        GridLayout,
        GridItem
    },
    data() {
        return {
            layout: [
                {"x":0,"y":0,"w":6,"h":4,"i":"0", static: false},
            ],
            draggable: true,
            resizable: true,
            index: 0
        }
    },
    methods: {
        itemTitle(item) {
            let result = item.i;
            if (item.static) {
                result += " - Static";
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.vue-grid-layout {
    background: #eee;
}
.vue-grid-item:not(.vue-grid-placeholder) {
    background: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.vue-grid-item .resizing {
    opacity: 0.9;
}
.vue-grid-item .static {
    background: #cce;
}
.vue-grid-item .text {
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.vue-grid-item .no-drag {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.vue-grid-item .minMax {
    font-size: 12px;
}
.vue-grid-item .add {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.vue-draggable-handle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='10' height='10'><circle cx='5' cy='5' r='5' fill='#999999'/></svg>") no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom right;
    padding: 0 8px 8px 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-origin: content-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

So basically i should not be able to drag or move the item from inside the container. Any kind of advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Since you asked you probably already solved your problem, but the easy way to avoid moving the entire item is to declare an attribute of grid-item where dragging is not allowed.

```
<grid-item class=""
             drag-allow-from=".vue-draggable-handle"
             drag-ignore-from=".no-drag"
             :autoSize="true" :x="item.x" :y="item.y" :w="item.w" :h="item.h" :i="item.i">
  <div class="vue-draggable-handle"></div>
  <div class="no-drag"></div>
</grid-item>
```

Thoses two attributes are in fact css class reference.

```
.vue-grid-item .no-drag {height: 100%;width: 100%;}
.vue-draggable-handle { position: initial; width: 5px;height: 5px;top: 0;right: 0;padding: 0 8px 8px 0;background-origin: content-box;box-sizing: border-box;border-radius: 10px;cursor: pointer;color: #005B60 !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either set static to true which would not allow you to drag/resize the grid or add an element draggable in your layout and set it to false where you will be able to only resize the grid.

```
layout: [
            {"x":0,"y":0,"w":6,"h":4,"i":"0", static: true},
        ] // If you want to lock the grid (no resize/no dragging)
```

or

```
layout: [
            {"x":0,"y":0,"w":6,"h":4,"i":"0", draggable: false},
        ] // you will be able to resize but drag
<grid-item
     :key="item.i"
      v-for="item in layout"
      :is-draggable="item.draggable"
      :x="item.x"
      :y="item.y"
      :w="item.w"
      :h="item.h"
     :i="item.i"
     >
```